# How to resolve the mysql error "insufficient memory" during mysql_init in c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, memory, ubuntu-12.04, init

I have a problem with a new deployement of a server program "MyServer" on **Ubuntu 12.04**.
**This program works fine on the 1st machine**.

But on the new machine, the program MyServer return an exception during **mysql_init()**:
"*Insufficient memory: can not create handler for mysql_init()*"

However these 2 machines have both 2Go RAM and MySQL seems to be well-installed (we can run request from mysql client) and have the same *my.cnf*.

This error appears during these lines :

```
sql::Driver * driver = get_driver_instance();

if(driver)
{
    // Lets try to connect.
    std::stringstream completeHost;
    completeHost << "tcp://"
                << (configuration->getSocket()->getHost())
                << ":"
                << (configuration->getSocket()->getPort());

    ////// **It throws this exception below** : //////
    sql::Connection * connection = driver->connect(completeHost.str(),
                                                   configuration->getUser(),
                                                   configuration->getPassword());
}
```

And the connection parameters are correct, since this is the same used with mysql client.

What's wrong ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across the same problem and I may have found a workaround. 
We also had two machines, one with our software working and the other one throwing the same message `Insufficient memory: can not create handler for mysql_init()`.

After a while, we noticed that the second machine went through some package updates. `libmysqlclient18` was one of these packages.

Once i downgraded my `libmysqlclient18` from 5.5.38 to 5.5.22 (the same version that the working one) it started working again !